# Apache Avro compile failing due to generated variables missing dollar signs

Tags: java, avro, velocity, gradle-plugin

I am setting up an Apache Avro module to be used for serializing and deserializing messages to Kafka.

I've tried various Gradle plugins, and they are all resulting in different errors.

The `org.betterplugin.avro` plugin seems to get me the closest, as it generates the Java and protocol files. However, one of the generated Java files has errors due to a missing dollar sign on one of the generated variables.

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "org.betterplugin.avro" version "0.19.2-SNAPSHOT"

    // Error: Unable to find resource '/org/apache/avro/compiler/specific/templates/java/classic/enum.vm'
    // id "com.bakdata.avro" version "1.0.1"

    // Error: Could not find method generateAvroProtocol()
    // id "com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro-base" version "1.3.0"

    // Error: property 'outputDir' is missing an input or output annotation.
    // id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.99.99"
}

group = 'com.example'
description = 'AVRO Library'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0"
}

generateAvroProtocol {
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    outputDir = file("build/generated-main-avro-protocol")
}

generateAvroJava {
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    outputDir = file("build/generated-main-avro-java")
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: EXAMPLE_A = value != null ? value$.toString() : null; break;
    case 1: EXAMPLE_B = value != null ? value$.toString() : null; break;
    case 2: EXAMPLE_C = value != null ? value$.toString() : null; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }
```

The `value$` parameter is referenced in the null check without the dollar sign which fails to compile with `cannot find symbol variable value`.

This is generated from `avro-compiler`'s `record.vm` template:

```
  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
#set ($i = 0)
#foreach ($field in $schema.getFields())
    case $i: ${this.mangle($field.name(), $schema.isError())} = #if(${this.javaType($field.schema())} != "java.lang.Object" && ${this.javaType($field.schema())} != "java.lang.String")(${this.javaType($field.schema())})#{end}value$#if(${this.javaType($field.schema())} == "java.lang.String") != null ? value$.toString() : null#{end}; break;
#set ($i = $i + 1)
#end
    default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + field$);
    }
  }
```

The template uses the dollar sign, so I'm not sure how this is getting missed.

Comment: I have a temporary workaround that allows the build to compile by doing a series of Gradle tasks that string edit the file using filter. This is a really terrible hack though.            `filter { String line -> line.replace(" = value ", " = value\$ ").replace(")value;", ")value\$;")  }`

Answer (score 1):

If I use the plugin name as `com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro` instead of `com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro-base`, I'm able to generate the java and protocol files

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro" version "1.3.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0"
}

generateAvroJava {
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    include("**/*.avsc")
    outputDir = file("build/generated-main-avro-java")
}

generateAvroProtocol {
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    include("**/*.avdl")
    outputDir = file("build/generated-main-avro-java")
}
```

**Generated avpr:**

```json
{
  "protocol" : "ExampleMessage",
  "namespace" : "example.avro",
  "types" : [ {
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "ExampleMessage",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "body",
      "type" : "string"
    } ]
  } ],
  "messages" : { }
}
```

**Generated put method:**

```java
  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: body = value$ != null ? value$.toString() : null; break;
    default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + field$);
    }
  }
```

The `$` signs are correct in the generated java files which are getting compiled into class files successfully

Comment: Did you get error while building a project? 

cannot access JsonParserpublic static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse

Comment: No, I did not get any error. You can find my sample project on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/java-demo/tree/avro-gradle). It generates the java files from avro schema and compiles fine when I run `./gradlew clean build`